# LTspice counter component how does it works?

Tags: ltspice, counter

I find this component on LTspice but I have some troubles to know how it works. It asks me to enter 2 parameters. I could understand that It needs to know the "divide" number but what is the second parameter ? I supposed one of the outputs is the complementary of the other

[image]

Thank you very much,

Have a nice day !

Comment: You didn’t mention what the second parameter is called. Why not show a screen shot of the two parameters.

Comment: I didn t know that it was possilbe to see how the parameters are called !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the component and in the field "Value" indicate "cycles=10". Change the value 10 to the desired cycles.
Obviously, connect a clock signal (voltage source as pulse) to the Clk input and connect GND to the pin in the left-bottom corner. Phi1 and Phi2 are outputs.

Comment: Also, when in doubt, check what [undocumented](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#Counter_.28divide_by_n.29:) features exist.

Comment: Thank you for the link ! :D